# Empty asymptotic confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, likelihood-ratio, likelihood, asymptotics

I have a sample $x=(4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4)$ of size $n=20$. from a binomial distribution with 10 trials and probability of success $p$. I am asked to construct the asymptotic 95% confidence interval based on the likelihood. I think this should be the set
$$
C = \left\{ p \in (0,1) : \prod_{i=1}^{n} p^{x_i} (1-p)^{10-x_i}\geq \exp(-q/2) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\overline{x}_n/10)^{x_i} (1-\overline{x}_n/10)^{10-x_i} \right\}
$$
where q is the $0.95$ quantile of the $\chi^2_1$ distribution. If I take logs of both sides, the inequality becomes
\begin{align*}
&n\overline{x}_n\log p  + (n10 - n\overline{x}_n)\log(1-p) \\
&\quad \quad \geq -q/2 + n\overline{x}_n\log(\overline{x}_n/10) + (n10 - n\overline{x}_n)\log(1-\overline{x}_n/10)
\end{align*}
If I plug in the data, it becomes
$$
59\log p + 141\log(1-p) \geq -123.2343
$$

The problem is that this inequality is not satisfied for any $p \in (0,1)$, implying that the confidence set $C$ is empty.

EDIT: The previous sentence is false. I was plotting the function on too large a scale to notice that it does indeed poke above $-123.2343$ briefly. I suppose the question in the title still stands.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Is something like this https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/41003/42850 going on here?

Comment: If the sample is independent binomials with common success probability, you can just combine the observations - i.e. 52 successes in 200 trials. That might at least simplify things a little, reducing the chances of dropping a sign or something.

Comment: The solution to your inequality is approximately $[0.234682, 0.360537]$ (readily found by Newton-Raphson or almost any other root finding algorithm). The sample mean $59/200 = 0.295$ is right in the middle.  The half-width of around $0.06$ is just about twice the standard error of $0.0322$, as one would expect.